# Determine The Probability of This Happening 3 Times

Tags: probability

I'm in over my head and need some assistance here.

So here's the deal... I bought 3 cases of toys. Each case comes with 24 toys and there are 108 possible toys in the set. I got the exact same 24 toys in each case, what are the odds of that happening?

I mean there is no way that should happen and the odds have got to be astronomical. Any assistance would be much appreciated because I contacted customer support and they claim its all random! But there's just no way, so I'd love to be able to hit them with a figure.

Comment: Toys (and other collectibles) are often packed in a fixed sequence for each rarity class. The probabilities for individual toys/cards/whatever are not independent. Effectively, the only random element is where in the sequence the case starts.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the first set of the toys. To have the same 24 toys in the second set if the toys are chosen at random, there is exactly one possibility among $$\binom{108}{24}=\frac{108!}{24!84!}\approx 6,4418234707535 \cdot 10^{23}
$$
To have third case of toys consisting with the same toys, one need one case of $6,4418234707535 \cdot 10^{23}$ too. The odds are $$(6,4418234707535 \cdot 10^{23})^2\approx 4,14970896283507\cdot 10^{47}.$$

Therefore if toys are chosen at random, you have the probability 
$$
\frac{1}{4,14970896283507\cdot 10^{47}} \approx 2,40980755266462\cdot 10^{-48}$$
to get three cases of the same toys.

Comment: As pointed out in another comment, however, it is unlikely that the toys were selected according to the randomizing assumptions in this answer.

Comment: Even if we were to ignore the dependence of the events in reality, this answer assumes that you cannot get duplicates within a single case.  In my experience with blind-bag figures and the like, this also doesn't necessarily happen.  It also ignores the possibility that some may be rarer than others and instead treats each toy as having the same probability to appear.  That being said... if we were to allow for selections to repeat, it only makes the scenario described even rarer, but if we allow for different rarities we'd need much more info.

Comment: Yea I agree with you David K that it is highly unlikely that the toys would be randomly selected in a manner like this. For example they would not put 24 of the exact same toys in a case, nor would they put 24 of the rarest toy in one case. But the answer by NCh was exactly what I was seeking for use in an argument and I greatly appreciate it. Unfortunately my puny brain cant even comprehend this number and I dont even know how to say it. For example: The odds of getting 3 exact cases are 1 in X number. What is X?

Comment: @Blizzo $X=414 970 896 283 507 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000 000$ approximately.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that the real-life chance of getting 3 boxes with identical sets of toys is a lot less astronomical than in [NCh’s answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2395098/265466), but the odds are still pretty long.

For a *very* rough estimate, let’s assume that the toys come off the line and go into boxes in a particular sequence, that there are no repetitions in that sequence, and that there’s a single rarity level. Assuming also that the point in the sequence at which any box that you get begins is uniformly distributed, then the chance of getting three of the same box is $$\left(\frac1{108}\right)^3=1259712^{-1}\approx7.94\times10^{-7}.$$ Repetitions will increase the chance of coincidence, but even if this is off by an order of magnitude, it’s still much less than a one-in-a-hundred-thousand occurrence. One factor that could drive this estimate up dramatically is the fact that $24$ divides $2\times108$, so there’s the possibility of the sequence repeating more often that this. On the other hand, different rarity levels will drive this number down rather than up. To get the same contents, several packing sequences would have to sync up simultaneously.